# Swap being consumed despite ram being empty

Tags: ram, swap

I was heavy tasking a while ago which probably lead to swap being used, probably the first time. But now there is still data in swap even though ram is free. [image]

Comment: read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq, seek for swapiness

Answer (score 2):

Fear not. This is expected behavior.

The kernel does not blindly copy back and forth between RAM and Swap. It's a bit more clever than that. Rarely-used data may remain in swap for quite a while.